# I got error while connecting to mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, undefined, dotenv

I have folder structure as

.env

```
    MONGODB_URL = mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB
```

.config

```
    export default {
        MONGODB_URL: process.env.MONGODB_URL
    }
```

.server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import config from './config'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
const app = express()
const PORT = 5000

dotenv.config()

const MONGODB_URL = config.MONGODB_URL

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URL,{
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, error=>{
    if(error){
        console.log("Error occurred "+error)
    }else{
        console.log("Database successfully connected")
    }
})

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log("Server started at port "+PORT)
})
```

Now it throws error as Error [MongooseError]: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

If I put string directly in .config file as

```
export default {
        MONGODB_URL: "mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB"
    }
```

It works perfectly but, if I use `process.env.MONGODB_URL` then it throws the error which I have mentioned above. Why it is throwing error when I use `process.env.MONGODB_URL` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assign variables in `.env` without whitespaces around assignment sign `=`

```
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB
```

`dotenv` will load the variables in `.env` file and assign it to `process.env` when you call `dotenv.config()`, which happens after when you imported `./config`.

But you can not call `dotenv.config()` before an `import` statement, so `dotenv` provides you an option to use `import 'dotenv/config'`, so you have to make sure that line comes before `import config from './config'`, best way is to put it at the top.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv/config'
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import config from './config'

const MONGODB_URL = config.MONGODB_URL
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the dotenv on the `.config` file, but the dontenv is not available on it.

A good approach is create a `config` directory with a index.js file inside of it, there you can share the environment variables and use the dotenv module in your code.

Your code will be something like this:

**config/index.js**:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
    MONGODB_URL: process.env.MONGODB_URL,
};
```

**.env**:

```
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB
```

And then you be able to use the env variable anywhere you want simply calling:

**server.js**:

```
const config = require('../config');
console.log(`Mongo URL: ${config.MONGODB_URL}`)
```

In this way your code get a little more organized "IMHO".